# Question about derivations in Sakurai's Quantum mechanics, section 5.8

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

If anyone is familiar with Sakurai's book, specifically section 5.8 on energy shift and decay width, I am stuck and could use some help. I can't see how he derives 5.8.9 (in the revised edition). He starts with (3) (given below), and derives (1) and (2). The equation is as follows:$$(1){\space}{\space}\space{\space}\space{\space}{\dot c_i\over c_i}\approx{{-i\over \hbar}V_{ii}+{\left(-i \over \hbar\right)}^2{{{\left|V_{ii}\right|}^2}\over \eta}+\left({-i\over \hbar}\right) {\sum_{m\not=i}}{{{\left|V_{mi}\right|}^2}\over {(E_i-E_m+i\hbar\eta)}} \over 1-{i \over \hbar}{V_{ii} \over \eta}} $$ $$(2)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\approx{-i\over \hbar}V_{ii}+\left({-i\over \hbar}\right) {\sum_{m\not=i}}{{{\left|V_{mi}\right|}^2}\over {(E_i-E_m+i\hbar\eta)}}$$ where $$(3)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,c_i(t)=\lim_{\eta\to 0}\left({1-{i\over \hbar\eta}V_{ii}}{e^{{\eta}t}}+{{\left({-i\over \hbar}\right)}^2}{{\left|V_{ii}\right|}^2}{e^{2{\eta}t}\over 2{\eta}^2}+\left({-i\over \hbar}\right){\sum_{m\not=i}{{{{\left|V_{mi}\right|}^2}}\over 2\eta(E_i-E_m+i{\hbar}\eta}}\right)$$First of all, the expression (3) for $c_i(t)$ itself is strange because in the limit as $\eta\to0$, all three terms dependent on $\eta$ blow up, and the probability interpretation is out the window. Then he discards all kinds of terms in the denominator to arrive at the first expression using (3), and I can't see how he justifies this. Then he seems to multiply top and bottom by the complex conjugate of the denominator in (1), arriving at (2) after discarding a term in the denominator, which is of second order in V. Then he goes on to say the equation is formally correct up to second order. This doesn't make sense to me! Also, soon after, he has this strange expression with $$\lim_{x\to 0} {1\over(x+iε)}=Pr.(1/x)-iπδ(x)$$ What is this Pr symbol? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please do not delete and repost your question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161251/

Comment: See the definition of [(Cauchy) principal value function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)

Comment: thanks! I've never seen it written that way, good to know!